# Google places API should only match keyword to place name, not the address

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using the Places API (not using GoogleApiClient, I'm calling the URL explicitly) to get nearby points of interest querying with a given keyword parameter. Problem is that the service also lists places with an address matching the keyword, but I'd like to list only the places with matching names.
Is there a way for this without filtering the results on client side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, keyword parameter is

> A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content

There is also a name parameter that seems to be the solution for you:

> One or more terms to be matched against the names of places, separated by a pipe symbol (term1|term2|etc). Results will be restricted to those containing the passed name values. Note that a place may have additional names associated with it, beyond its listed name. The API will try to match the passed name value against all of these names. As a result, places may be returned in the results whose listed names do not match the search term, but whose associated names do.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem to work either. I solved the issue by filtering the results on the client side.